# A very large cpu spike when using mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, cpu-usage

I have an array of 750 users in my users collection.

I'm using this code with mongoose and i get incredible cpu jump (98% - 103%) in the process:

```
 var stream = User.find({}).stream();
        stream.on('data', function(user) {
        stream.pause();
        user.someObj += (conditionTrue)? do one thing : do another;
        ...(some other changes)
        user.save(function(err, doc) {
            stream.resume();
        });
    }).on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }).on('close', function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
```

Is it normal? i don't think so, is it? (this operation takes about 5 seconds or so, but still, cpu jump is a killer...)

Comment: When the CPU is doing work, it's working. That's what the CPU monitor is telling you. If you're saying it's using too much resource, you'll need to optimise your operations somehow, but if it's not a problem for you then it's not a problem (though 5 seconds is a long time). Also remember that using 100% CPU doesn't mean that nothing else can use the CPU. We've had multi-process, multi-threaded fair CPU allocation capabilities for decades now.

Comment: Im talking about only this code, no users online (staging area), only when i run this code i have this spike...

Comment: My point is that you've asked the CPU to do something, so it's doing it. The fact that it's got nothing else to do, and is therefore dedicating 100% to your problem, is a good thing (and if your server has multiple CPUs and your program is making use of all of them it means it's successfully multi-threading). Using 100% of the CPU is not a problem. If another task comes along, that resource will be shared as needed. Don't worry about it. What *is* a problem is that it is taking 5 seconds when given the full resource. Imagine how long it will take if 10 of the same request come in...

Comment: Dip down into the native driver and use [bulk writes](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) if you want better performance.